# Kerberos password

Tags: macos, password, kerberos

First of all, I have no idea how Kerberos ended up in my Mac. I have tried to reset its password but I don't even know what is the ID to use.  So, please how do I reset Kerberos password when I have no clue about which server it is connecting to?

I am running El Capitan 10.11.3 on MacBook Pro.

No. I don't know Kerberos password. :(

Answer (score 1):

Open keychain access, from the **Keychain Access** menu select **Ticket Viewer**.  There you will see your kerberos tickets which you can select and then hit the **Change Password** button.

This assumes that you know the current password.  If you don't, then you may need to provide more details in order to get help.